# Objective C: How to create border effect around photos

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimage

Can anyone advise me on how I can create a border around photos (like what you see in the screen shot below)? It seems like there is a thin grey border and a drop shadow at the back.

Appreciate any advise here.

[image]

Comment: @highlycaffeinated, I have tried to import QuartzCore lib and use the border property but the effects were not satisfactory... hence thought of asking around to see if there are any other approaches to it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple way: wrap the photo into a `UIImageView`, setup the `borderColor`, `cornerRadius`, `shadowColor`, `shadowOffset`, `shadowPath` etc. for the layer of the UIImageView.

Complex way: subclass the UIView and draw the border and shadow by yourself in `-drawRect:`.

Comment: You might want to specify that in order to alter the settings for the UIImageView, you need to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`, and access the `layer` property of the `UIImageView` to change the aforementioned properties of the image.